Getting errors while implementing Azure AD B2C authentication on my ASP.NET Core web application
To setup B2C authentication on my application, I have performed the required steps i.e. B2c tenant creations and app registration. But I'm getting this error:

I read through bunch of articles on Microsoft learn and followed their and other tutorials as well. It seems that the same method and configuration seems to work for them. Please look through the approach and try to provide your knowledge on any fails causing this.
I have tried this configuration in Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
//    {
//        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
//        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
//        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
//        // Handling SameSite cookie according to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1
//        options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
//    });

builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, Constants.AzureAdB2C);
        // .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        // .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

// builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        //     .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

// Add the authorization policies
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
        });

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

// Configuring appsettings section AzureAdB2C, into IOptions
// builder.Services.AddOptions();
// builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();

And I have this config in appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAdB2C": {
      "Instance": "https://partnerportal.b2clogin.com",
      "ClientId": "d5f02334-abcd-4414-b34c-460f6e4b5e19",
      "Domain": "partnerportal.onmicrosoft.com",
      "SignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_ppp_signin_demo",
      "CallbackPath":"/sigin-oidc"
  }
}


Firstly, we have tutorial here along with a sample. We might follow them to create a Sign in and sign up user flow. Then I checked your error message and the configuration, In your settings, tenant name is partnerportal while in the error message, it's randomname. In the mean time, the client id in your configuration

is d5f0233xxx-xxx while in the screenshot it's 1816exxxx-xxx``. It's important to setup correct configuration as the error message indicating that it cannot fetch the OpenID Connect metadata from Azure AD B2C which always mean the wrong configuration. Pls follow the tutorial and check them.

@TinyWang, please ignore the mismatched configuration for clientid and doamin-name you see, I have altered the config details on purpose in the screenshot. I assure you that I have matched all the values required to connect with AD B2C multiple times.

Thanks for your kind reply, then could you pls take a look at the sample in the link I shared with you, then just modify the configuration with your tenant information to see whether it worked or not? Please bear with me that I'm afraid there's something wrong with the resources you created.... So that I still recommend testing with the sample code.

The problem is with SignInPolicyId parameter in AppSettings.json file, which needs to be replaced with SignUpSignInPolicyId. Even though I am using sign-in only policy but the key name must be SignUpSignInPolicyId.
Got the solution from here: link

The problem is with SignInPolicyId parameter in AppSettings.json file, which needs to be replaced with SignUpSignInPolicyId. Even though I am using sign-in only policy, but the key name must be SignUpSignInPolicyId.
Got the solution from here: link
